# Create and update a data matrix from lists?

Tags: excel, matrix

This may be completely the wrong place to ask this, apologies in advance if so.

I have an Excel workbook with this structure:

- Sheet1: List of items (A)
- Sheet2: List of items (B)
- Sheet3: Matrix of items A (rows) to items B (columns), with items manually entered

The matrix is used to manually define relationships between A and B. The relationship is just an X at the relevant intersection to show that itemA relates to that itemB.

From the matrix, I create:

- Sheet4: Power Query 'unpivot' of Sheet3 to generate SQL inserts

The problem is that item lists in Sheet1 and Sheet2 aren't tied to Sheet3. If I add, remove, or change something in Sheet1 or Sheet2, I need to manually add or change rows or columns Sheet3. I've not found a way to do this automatically.

- Simple solutions like VLOOKUPs risk off-by-one errors and don't create or remove new columns.
- A series of Power Queries might work, but I haven't managed to come up with a conceptual framework for this.
- Pivot tables appear to be one-way only
- Using the matrix alone as the primary source (dispensing with the lists) would work for this simple case, but the full workbook also has B/C, B/D, C/D etc. matrices, so having a single list for each item type seems more appropriate.

Sample requirements:

- Add Sheet2 item, matrix adds column with item, ideally in the same list order as Sheet2
- Remove Sheet2 item, matrix removes column with item, discarding any relationships defined in that column
- Change Sheet2 item, matrix changes the item

Is this possible to achieve in Excel? if not, how can I achieve this with a GUI-based mechanism outside of Excel? I assume I need something in front of a database to preserve the correct A/B relationships as they're defined. Otherwise, this is very much a green field project.

Comment: Maybe the concept of self referencing tables can help here. See [Matt's article](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/)

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks. That actually solves half the problem: I can update the Y-axis (or in this case, Sheet1) and have it carry over. But how can I do the same with column creation/removal on the X-axis (from Sheet2)?

Comment: One option could be to normalize the information and instead of having n numbers of columns, you could repeat the coincidences in a single column so List of items B would be repeated for each item in List of Items A. The second option could be to modify the M code via VBA in order to include new columns, but I don't know if that would break the self referencing process. You'd have to test it.